# Window is not a constructor error?

Tags: javascript

I have this code in a JavaScript file:

```
this.tooltipWindow = new Window("__tooltip__", TooltipManager.options);
```

This gives me the `TypeError: Window is not a constructor` error in Firefox. Is there something wrong with this code and yes, how can I rewrite it, so it works?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you have a type defined by the word "Window", it's likely interfering with the actual 'window' object that exists on all pages.

If you're actually trying to create a new 'Window', as in the browser-typed object, that way, then I think that you're entering into some unfamiliar areas to me...are you just trying to create a popup window?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.open

Comment: I dont know the code, its not mine, but looking at it, it seems to open a popup window, yes.

Comment: I figured it out, there was another file which defined the Window class. All done and thanks for helping out!

Comment: Unfortunately, a brief test in all browsers indicates that this is not proper usage. Without looking at the whole of the code in question, the most straightforward answer is that either someone didn't know what they were doing, and posted that code anyway...? OR, they define their own Window type in some way. `window.open` should be the browser function you're looking for. Edited with more info.

Answer (score 0):

A quick search on that line of code pointed me to a library called ATK, specifically the tooltip.js file. At first glance it's quite a complete library, but it seems like you are only using tooltip.js. Since the Window class is defined in window.js you'll need to include that script as well to make it work.
I don't know the framework myself, so it might be wise to check if it even supports cherry-picking specific pieces of code like that.